# preventing menu item from re-firing once inside

Tags: jquery

upon entering my menu item my hidden div rolls down nicely then recoils if you leave. the problem is if you are already mousing around the container then RE-enter the menu item up top it unfortunately re-fires and slides the hidden container down again like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/17/

so what I'm trying to do is test to see if the item is already visible, if it is simply keep showing the container.

close as I can get to that is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/18/

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do a hover state menu like that? It's not going to work so well on touch-screens.

Comment: This was answered here already:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360209/cancel-all-queued-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-animations

Comment: @DrewBaker. thanks for pointing that out. I think so, this is for a site targeted mainly at non-mobile users. curious though, what would be a good fall back? check to see if it's a mobile device, then make the drop downs clickable?

Comment: and thank you for that link.. missed that one. I was searching on stop instead of cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the way you have it setup check it out here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henesnarfel/NAyWQ/20/).  Also Hogan gave you a good answer if you want the dropdwon menus contained within the main menu.  Otherwise I just added a `stop(true, true)` call on the `#dd_about` to make the animation stop.

Comment: ahah.. you've got to stop the function already working on the container before it will listen to the css change command. that's the bit I was missing. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/DLFm3/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="boundary"></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="about">
                 <div id="dd_about"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var menustate = "hidden";

$('#about').bind('mouseenter', function() {       

    if (menustate == "hidden")
    {
        $('#dd_about').slideDown('fast');
        menustate = "shown";
    }
});


$('#about').bind('mouseleave', function () {
      $('#dd_about').slideUp('fast');
    menustate = "hidden";
});​
```

css

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;    
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}

#boundary {
    width:320px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:purple;

}

#menu {
     width:100px;
     height:40px;
     position:absolute;
     right:10px;
     top:10px;   
}

#about {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    background:yellow;

 }

#dd_about  {
   top : 40px;
   left : 0px;
   width:100px;
   height:200px;
   position:absolute; 
   background:red;
   display:none;
} 

#dd_about {right:10px}
```

as does this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DLFm3/1/

with this javascript

```
$('#about').bind('mouseenter', function() {       

        $('#dd_about').slideDown('fast');
});


$('#about').bind('mouseleave', function () {
      $('#dd_about').slideUp('fast');
});​


​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/21/

This example uses flag variable to check current hover state

```
var hover = false;

$('#about').bind('mouseenter', function() {      
    hover = true;
    $('#dd_about').slideDown('fast');
});

$('#boundary').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    hover = false;
    $('#dd_about').slideUp('fast');
});

$('#dd_about').bind('mouseleave', function () {
    hover = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (hover) return false; 
        $('#dd_about').slideUp('fast');
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: thanks @dfsq I was trying a solution like that initially. works as well.