# jQuery : slideDown() , slideUp() and stop()

Tags: jquery, jquery-slide-effects

I have a menu strip . I planned to :

1. `slideDown()` a submenu ( originally `display: none` DIV ) when I **mouse over** the menu strip
2. hide the submenu by `slideUp` when **mouse out**.

Here is the codes:

```
<div id="main_menu" onmouseover="$('#submenu').stop(true,false).slideDown();" onmouseout="$('#submenu').stop(true,false).slideUp();">Main Menu</div>
<div id="submenu" style="display: none">Some submenu contents here</div>
```

What I try to achieve is, when I mouseover submenu，the submenu holds and stop the mouse out ( the `slideUp()` animation. How can I achieve it ?

Note: given that the **main_menu** and **sub_menu** did not overlap.

**UPDATE**: here is the the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/9KfYr/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way you can do is adding a parent dom, and binding the mouse event to it.

html

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="main_menu">Main Menu</div>
    <div id="submenu" style="display: none">Some submenu contents here</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#menu').hover(function () {
    $('#submenu').stop(true, false).slideDown();
},

function () {
    $('#submenu').stop(true, false).slideUp();
});
```

here is jsfiddle demo. http://jsfiddle.net/vyDVd/

**update**

If you don't want to adding  a parent dom, you can try putting `submenu` into `main_menu` as a child menu.

I update your jsfiddle demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/9KfYr/2/

I add 2 css attributes to `#submenu` to keep UI unchange.

```
position:absolute;
top:30px;
```

And here, I suggest use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) provided by jQuery.

Comment: looks good, but if my Main Menu has multiple menu items, and I only want 1 of the menu items to have mouse over effects only, how can I achieve it ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor since you need only one, you can put `submenu` into `main_menu` as a child dom, then do that like my post will be an easy way.

Comment: would you mind to try update my jsFiddle? I tried putting the submenu into main_menu, but it will alter the user interface. ( my jsFiddle link is in the question )

Comment: if you mouseleave and instantly mouseover - it stucks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was able to achive this using pure css:

```css
.header-submenu-item {
 display:none;
}
.header-parent-link:hover + .header-submenu-item,
.header-submenu-item:hover {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-parent-link">Item 1</div>
  <div class="header-submenu-item"></div><!-- Empty submenu -->
<div class="header-parent-link">Item 2</div>
  <div class="header-submenu-item">
    <a href="#">Child Item</a>
    <a href="#">Child Item</a>
    <a href="#">Child Item</a>
  </div>
```

It doesn't include slideDown() effect, but is very simple. I guess, slidedown can be achieved using other css effects.

Comment: It's nicely done! However, it probably needs a fallback plan for older browsers. (p.s. It's better to use `<nav>` tag for navigations)

Comment: Maybe.

But you know what, actually, I did just check on www.w3schools.com, and they don't even specify the earliest browser versions for the + selector, except for IE, which is 7. So I guess it's not much of a problem.

I did use nav, only as a menu wrapper, and these are its child items

Comment: Never trust w3schools, their tutorials are full of errors. Refer to MDN instead.